# How do I access exFAT files on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, exfat

I can open an external hard drive with a windows computer but not with my MacBook Pro.

About my MBP:

- OS: `Monterey 12.5.1 (21G83)`
- Hardware: `MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)`
- Processor: `2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9`
- Memory: `32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4`

About the external drive:

- USB Connection (NOT type-c)
- 5TB
- partitions: Just one volume with one folder at root path, but a lot of small folders and files in that folder

[image]

I have googled some articles, but most of them are telling me how to format/erase the disk.

Is there any way I can do that? I only need to read the files.

Comment: What specific models of Macs, when version of macOS, and what connection (USB? FireWire? USBC?) What size is the exFAT drive? Any partitions? exFAT drives are usually readable on Macs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have updated the question.

Comment: If you are connecting the drive to a _USB3 Dock_, try connecting directly to the MBP itself.

Comment: Is the dock or the disk plugged to power supply ? Because in some cases, the mac cannot provide enough power for a dock and a disk chained (or the dock prevents it) - especially a hard disk, which has a motor. (Do you feel the disk turning, or is a LED lighting up ?)

Comment: Note : exFAT should be read natively by a mac.

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried to connect to another iMac directly, but also not working

Comment: @Pierre Thanks, I don't have a type-C wire for this but I tried to connect it with my iMac, and failed. Looks like I have to copy from my Windows computer.

Comment: @Pierre Looks like https://www.reddit.com/r/editors/comments/oln12b/solutions_for_an_exfat_drive_not_mounted_on_mac/ explains why this is not working. Maybe it's just too large.

Comment: @AGamePlayer Yes, probably the wrong allocation unit size, as mentioned. Thank you very much for the follow-up !

Comment: If you want 'correct' rather than custom/random block allocation sizes, reformat it in the Mac. [Copy your data off first, of course.]